# Creating a Gtk.Image from a pixel list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk, gobject-introspection

I am working on a GTK program that manipulates an image based on user input. I am using [pypng](https://github.com/drj11/pypng) to read the image and am now looking for a way to create a `Gtk.Image` from a pixel list without creating an intermediate image file.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely easy to do in Python directly. You could do this, using `GtkImage`, which can load images from a `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf` using a method called `from_pixdata()`.

A higher level of doing this is using (for example) [the `PIL` (in `python2`) or `Pillow` (`python3`)](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWsffNkdTTAhWCS5AKHXe_AlcQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpillow.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNGGAG1C2SW5xJ_FrBE4IqsCTmrbLA). There, you can construct images using the Image module and the P`IL.Image.frombytes()`, `PIL.Image.fromstring()`, and other methods.

There are also [functions in matplotlib which convert arrays](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html) immediately to images.